# Im getting invalid hook call error with useCallBack in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-usecallback

im getting invalid hook call error in my project.

```
 <DateBottomSheet
          key={keyIndexStartDate}
          currentDate={startDate}
          headerTitle={moment(startDate).format('MMMM YYYY')}
          backdropComponent={renderBackdrop}
          ref={sheetRefStartDate}
          snapPoints={snapPointsDateSheet}
          markedDates={markedStartDate}
          onChange={() => handleSheetChanges}
          renderArrow={renderCalendarRightAndLeftIcon}
          onPressArrowRight={()=>onPressCalendarRight(startDate, 'startDate')}
          onPressArrowLeft={()=>onPressCalendarLeft(startDate, 'startDate')}
          onDayPress={day => {
            setMarkedStartDateValue(day.dateString);
            pressOpenStartTimerAction();
            // handleSnapPress(1, CreateWorkyBS.startTime);
          }}
          onPressCancel={() =>
            handleCloseStartCalender(CreateWorkyBS.startDate)
          }
          onPressSave={() => saveStartDateItem()}
          saveButtonDisable={buttonStartDateDisable}></DateBottomSheet>
```

and is my OnpressCalendar function

```
const onPressCalendarRight = (date, type) => 
useCallback(add => {
  const addDate = moment(date).add(1, 'M');
  type == 'startDate' ? setStartDate(addDate) : setEndDate(addDate);
  add();
});
```

[Error Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27z9y.png)

Anyone help me ?

Comment: You are nesting the `useCallback` hook inside a function named `onPressCalendarRight`. This is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You are breaking the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html). `useCallback` is a hook, and as such can ONLY be called at the root level of a functional component.

It looks like you can simply remove the use of `useCallback` altogether to fix the issue, and call the embedded function directly in `onPressCalendarRight`.

```
const onPressCalendarRight = (date, type) => {
  const addDate = moment(date).add(1, 'M');
  type == 'startDate' ? setStartDate(addDate) : setEndDate(addDate);
}
```

Comment: It's a calendar function. This function renders the other month when the button is pressed. When I remove usecallback, the calendar part is not rendered. How can I do it?

Comment: @berkayer check my edit. Don't remove the whole function, just the `useCallback` part.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 Const onPressCalendarRight = useCallback((add) => (date,type) => {
 const addDate = moment(date).add(1, 'M');
  type == 'startDate' ? setStartDate(addDate) : setEndDate(addDate);
  add();
 },[AddDate]);
```

Comment: Nothing happens when you press the button

Comment: I have updated the code try now